# Python 3.6 pip install matplotlib and other libraries failed on Windows 10

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, conda, python-3.6

I have recently got a new laptop and I want to install all of my python libraries. However, some of them just won't install, like matplotlib.

About my computer: Windows 10 with Python 3.6, and according to pip, these libraries.

```
colorama (0.3.7)
Django (1.8.17)
Mathics (1.0)
mpmath (0.19)
pip (9.0.1)
python-dateutil (2.6.0)
setuptools (32.3.0)
six (1.10.0)
sympy (1.0)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

Result of "pip install matplotlib":

```
Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "", line 1, in 
    File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-1.5.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
 Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Error processing line 1 of c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\marvi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "", line 1, in 
        File "", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [1.5.3]
                    python: yes [3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016,
                            08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]]
                  platform: yes [win32]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [not found. pip may install it below.]
                  dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.6.0]
                      pytz: yes [pytz was not found. pip will attempt to install
                            it after matplotlib.]
                    cycler: yes [cycler was not found. pip will attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                   tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                            WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                 pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                            mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype (ft2build.h)
                            could not be found.  You may need to install the
                            development package.]
                       png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                            found.  You may need to install the development
                            package.]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                            found. Using local copy.]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                            matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
                            your preferred tool to run the test suite / using
                            unittest.mock]
            toolkits_tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                            matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
                            your preferred tool to run the test suite / using
                            unittest.mock]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                    qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                    qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
                   gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
                 gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                    gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                     tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                            Tk]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
                 windowing: yes [installing]

    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: no
               ghostscript: no
                     latex: no
                   pdftops: no

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                      dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype, png

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\marvi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-a0hjoody\matplotlib\
```

Basically, something about cached files,  a bunch of AttributeErrors from site.py and something about not having freetype or png. I tried to fix site.py, but it still doesn't work. I tried the .whl file from PyPi, and that doesn't work. I tried "pip install matplotlib --no-cache-dir", same thing. I tried manually downloading png and freetype, but I couldn't find them. Roughly the same thing happens with all the other libraries that I want to download: NumPy, SciPy, pandas.

Comment: Do you have other version of Python installed?

Comment: no. Unless Windows 10 comes with it

Comment: So, I've try to start a fresh Win 10 OS, installed python 3.6 and you are true. It comes without some packages... You can find Freetype [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/freetype/files/freetype2/2.7/) and the PNG one [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng16/). I hope this will help you

Comment: I dont think those are the python compatible ones, unless I'm doing something wrong. Right now, I'm just downloading the compressed folder and trying to run pip, is there a better way?

Comment: Try with this for [freetype](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/freetype/2.3.5-1/freetype-2.3.5-1-setup.exe/download?use_mirror=netcologne&download=) and this one for [PNG](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/libpng/1.2.37/libpng-1.2.37-setup.exe/download?use_mirror=netcologne). When you install the "exe" I think you are ok

Comment: Thanks, I'm on a phone so I can't test it right now.

Comment: @andrepogg That still doesn't work, i've went through all the setups, still deosnt work.

Comment: Do you get the same error?

Comment: I get a similar problem on OS X with 3.6

Comment: UPDATE:  On OS X, install freetype and PNG from the links that @andrepogg supplied worked fine.  Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, I get the same error.

Comment: If its any consolation, I tried the same procedure on Windows 10 and I get exactly the same, even with freetype and png installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use anaconda with Python 3.6 you can use:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python=3.6.0
conda install matplotlib --channel conda-forge
```

To download anaconda visit https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: However I don't have anaconda, so how do I download it

Comment: Thanks but not on computer so cant test it.

Comment: I decided to go to python 3.5.2 and downloaded anaconda, and got many libraries. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1.5.1 version does not have this problem,can you check this:

```
pip install matplotlib==1.5.1
```

Comment: 1.5.1 has the same output: a bunch of AttributeErrors and it can't find png or freetype.

Comment: I got this error : `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5rm3rvdv/matplotlib/`

Answer (score 0):

Like you I went around in circles over this one!

If you install from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib) it should be OK.  I used matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl, but there is a 64-bit version as well.

I installed using `cmd.exe` "Run as Administrator" with the python directories in my path:

```
pip3 install matplotlib-2.0.0rc2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
```

Comment: I got even more error messages: https://gist.github.com/ev3commander/3f1defb5cb440d7cddd4d2a6c89f2889

Comment: I feel like I have to delete all things related to python3.6 and download python3.5.4 because on my desktop with python3.5.4 it works fine...

Comment: I installed 3.6 in a different way to you, but I don't know if it would make a difference.  I did a "Customise installation" and in the "Advanced options" I checked "Install for all users".  That installs 3.6 into "Program Files (x86)" instead of the local App directory.  I had other issues with the local install.

Comment: Did you `pip3 install numpy` first?  Looking at your error messages, that might be the issue.

Comment: I get error messages that are the same as matplotlib without wheel. Also there are no Python 3.6 versions of numpy on pypi for windows

Comment: I installed `numpy` on Windows with `pip3 install numpy` and it worked fine.  I've now successfully installed `matplotlib` with Python 3.6.0 on Windows 10, OS X, and Linux (CentOS).  In each case I installed numpy first.

Comment: Just wanted to add my report that with 64-bit Python 3.6 on Windows 10, I was able to successfully "pip install numpy" followed by "pip install matplotlib"... that's all it took.  Much simpler than the steps I had to take under 2.7.